# Show $\Bbb{Z}_{30},\ \Bbb{Z}_5 \times D_3,\ \Bbb{Z}_3 \times D_5$ and $D_{15}$ are not isomorphic where $D_n$ is the dihedral group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I'm looking for a *hint* for the following problem:

> Show that no two elements of the following list are isomorphic ($D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$).
> $$\mathbb{Z}_{30},\ \mathbb{Z}_5 \times D_3,\ \mathbb{Z}_3 \times D_5 \text{ and }D_{15}$$

---

**My attempt**

I know that $\mathbb{Z_{30}}$ is abelian and $\mathbb{Z}_a\times D_b$ with $a\in\{3,5\}$ and $b\in\{3,5\}\setminus \{a\}$ isn't (because $D_n$ isn't, for all $n$) and thus $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ can't be isomorphic to any of the other elements of the list. The question is now reduced to the same problem but now with the list
$$\mathbb{Z}_5 \times D_3,\ \mathbb{Z}_3 \times D_5 \text{ and }D_{15}.$$
Here I'm completely stuck, I feel like I'm close to finding a propperty held by $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times D_3$ and not by $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times D_5$ but I'm not quite there. So I come here looking for a *hint*. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw (for context), this are the only groups (without accounting for isomorphisms) of order $30$. The problem previous to this one was to show that there were at most $4$ groups of order $30$.

Comment: Try computing the centres of each of the groups,  i.e. the subgroup of elements that commute with all other elements.

Comment: Let $N$ be the $5$-Sylow subgroup and consider $G/N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easier to me to use the following statement.
By the way, it is useful to remember it in any case.

> The group $D_n$ for odd $n$ has exactly $n$ involutions, i.e.,
> elements of order $2$.

If, for example, we define $D_n$ as a group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon,
then the elements of order $2$ are exactly all $n$ reflexions.

Now it is easy to see that the number of involutions for our groups is: $3$, $5$, and $15$.
So these three groups are pairwise non-isomorphic.